# SSMS - If query takes too long, cancel and move onto the next one

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, cursor

I have a cursor which loops through a long list of insert statements, each insert statement is fetched into my variable @sql then I do:
EXEC(@SQL)

Sometimes it takes less than a second to execute one insert statement and sometimes it takes over 15 minutes. Is there a way for me to tell the cursor to cancel the current query and move onto the next one if it's taking too long (over 20 seconds)?

Comment: Unfortunately you will not get functions to stop at SQL level unless you kill the process by capturing spid, it is much easier to do it on .net console instead of doing it in management studio.